# $\inf\{f(x) : x \in E \in \mathcal{M}, \mu(E) = \infty\} = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X , \mathcal{M} , \mu)$ a measure space and let $f : X \to [0 , + \infty]$ be a function such that $\int_X f d \mu < \infty$. Then I have to show that
$$
\inf\{f(x) : x \in E \in \mathcal{M}, \mu(E) = \infty\} = 0.
$$
My attempt is the next: if $\int_X f d \mu < \infty$, then $A = \{x \in X : f(x) > 0\}$ can be written as
$$
A = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n
$$
where
$$
A_n = \left\{x \in X : f(x) > \frac 1 n\right\}
$$
has finite mesure $\mu(A_n) \leq n \int_X f d \mu < \infty$. I think it's enough if we show that $A^c \neq \emptyset$. Is my argument helpful to show it? If $\mu(X) < \infty$, is $\{f(x) : x \in E \in \mathcal{M}, \mu(E) = \infty\} = \emptyset$?

Comment: If $\mu(X) < \infty$, wouldn't that $\inf$ be $\infty$?

Comment: It follows immediately by contradiction and the integral comparison test

Comment: what do you mean with "by contradiction", @FShrike?

Comment: Assuming otherwise, I think you can compare it to the integral of a non-zero simple function on $E$ and then show the integral of $f$ is non-finite

Comment: @FShrike do you mean that I could use the definition of $\int_X f d \mu = \sup \{\int_X \varphi d \mu : \varphi$ is simple and $\varphi \leq f\}$?

Comment: You can just compare it to $\varphi=c\cdot\chi_E$ where $c$ is the infimum. If $c\neq 0$, then we have $\int_X f\gt\int_X\varphi=\infty$

Comment: @FShrike it makes sense but I have one question. Let $A$ be the set $\{f(x) : x \in E \in \mathcal{M}, \mu(E) = \infty\}$. For the the infimum $c$ of $A$, we have to be sure that $c \in \mathbb{R}$ at least, is it ok? Can $c$ be $\infty$?. On the other hand, if $\mu(X) < \infty$, there is not $E \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(E) = \infty$. Then what is $A$ in that case? and $c$?

Comment: @FShrike But if $c$ is infinite, how can we define $\varphi = c {\chi}_E$? The fact of $\int_X f d \mu < \infty$ gives us that $f(x) < 0$ for almost all points $x \in X$, but I am not sure if is enough to show that there exists $x \in X$ that $f(x) < \infty$, what would be sufficient for $c < \infty$.

Comment: @FShrike there is an argument which I did not understand well. You said "if $c = \infty$ then you can take $c = 1$". Sorry but I did not understand very well what to do if we have $c = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid answering in the comments I've typed everything up here:

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Let $c$ equal the given infimum. As $f$ has nonnegative image, $c\ge0$. If $\mu(X)\lt\infty$ then the given question doesn't make sense, so suppose that this infimum is well defined; infimums always exist, so $c\in\Bbb R^+$ or $c=\infty$. If $c\ge1$, set $\alpha:=1$, and if $0\le c\le1$ put $\alpha:=c$.

Let $\varphi=\alpha\cdot\chi_E$ for some $E\in\mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(E)=\infty$ - we are assuming at least one $E$ exists. Then $\varphi\le f$ everywhere, since $\varphi=0\le f$ on $X\setminus E$ and $\varphi=\alpha\le c\le f$ on $E$.

Then by basic monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral:

$$\int_X\varphi\d\mu\le\int_Xf\d\mu$$

We are told that $\int_Xf\d\mu\lt\infty$. Suppose that $c\neq0$; then $\alpha\gt0$, and it follows from definition of the Lebesgue integral that:

$$\int_Xf\d\mu\ge\int_X\varphi\d\mu=\alpha\cdot\mu(E)=\infty,\,\alpha\gt0$$

Which is a contradiction; it then follows that $c=0$ since $c\neq0$ is  impossible, and $c\in\overline{\Bbb R}$.